# Extract Meta Description of the webpage using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to extract meta description of any webpage? I have used the below script to get the meta-information of the webpage.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dataquest.io/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

metas = soup.find_all('meta')
```

The result of the script is:

```
 [<meta charset="utf-8"/>,
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>,
 <meta content="Learn Python, R, and SQL skills. Follow career paths to become a job-qualified data scientist, analyst, or engineer with interactive data science courses!" name="description"/>,
 <meta content="index, follow" name="robots"/>,
 <meta content="index, follow, max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1" name="googlebot"/>,
 <meta content="index, follow, max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1" name="bingbot"/>,
 <meta content="en_US" property="og:locale"/>]
```

Now I want to pull the content of meta property where `name="description"` i.e, the second line in this case.

Kindly suggest!

Comment: Try `print(soup.find_all('meta')[2].get("name"))`

Comment: @SiddharthDushantha `print(soup.find_all('meta')[2].get("content"))` this worked fine. But I want to make it more generalised, since on every page description is not present at index 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the python array filtering syntax for this:

```
[m.get('content') for m in metas if m.get('name') == 'description']
```

This returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the description directly using

`soup.find_all("meta", attrs={'name': 'description'})`